# How to retrieve array of results of (has-many) relationship

Tags: laravel-9, relation, has-many

I have users table (id,email...etc)
and related table user_devices(user_id,device_id)

user has many devices

In User Model

```
 public function userDevices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(userDevicess::class, 'user_devices');
}
```

In controller

```
$userdevices=$user->with('userDevices')->where('device_id',$request->device_id)->get();
```

But it not works!

What I want:

```
foreach($userdevices  as $userdevice)
echo userdevice->email;
```

Thanks

Comment: try $userdevices=$user->userDevices()->where('device_id',$request->device_id)->get();

Comment: thanks for help, I've already done, but it gives error:` Column not found: 1054 Unknown column   userDevices.userDevices   in
    where clause   (SQL: select * from   userDevices   where
    userDevices  .  userDevices   =3  and   userDevices  .  userDevices   is not null and     device_id   = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)`

Comment: It seems as it take the relation as column name

Comment: i think you have wrong relationship .it should be belongsToMany

Comment: can you show all three table structure

Comment: They are 2 tables, You mean I need to separate tables, one for devices, users and  pivot table for them, then rebuild many-to-many relation..

Comment: yes look like that would be good way i guess